# Android: FrameLayout inside an LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build an TabHost android application. I have developed this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/navigation_bar_background"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:tabStripEnabled="true" >
                </TabWidget>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, the @id/tabcontent element covers all phone screen and does not want to allow space for @id/scroll. Why LinearLayout is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the @id/scroll always exists, 
Change your xml to this

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
```

>